# Why was my question which contains the code written by me closed as off topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

[Maintaining a count with two threads using conditional variables](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14214/maintaining-a-count-with-two-threads-using-conditional-variables)

I saw this closure today. Why is this closed as off topic? This contains code written by me, and I received a very nice answer.

What point am I missing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The cited reason for the closure is not that it was someone else's code, but that the code looked [hypothetical](/q/1981/9357).

Normally, function names like `foo`, `bar`, or `functionA` are indicators that the code is hypothetical.  Also, comments like `// Do something` are stub code.  Questions containing such vague code are generally unreviewable, since there is too much left to the imagination.

On the other hand, your question looks more like a simple demonstration that happens to have generic-looking function names.  It is a concrete program with a stated purpose.  You're asking for suggested improvements to the code and not generic best practices.

In my opinion, the question is on-topic.  Some users may still think that the example is a bit on the hypothetical side since the demonstration doesn't do anything very useful.  However, it's not a clear-cut case that merits closure by a single moderator's decision.  I've reopened the question.